# Flutter: Firebase maps of arrays

Tags: firebase, flutter

---

### Edit2:

The code I was writing below appears to work now, but I can't use it to populate ListTiles, so it doesn't seem useful for what I need to acheive.

I am stuck at this point:

```
Container(
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('User').document('ObjectsList').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return LoadingAnimation();
        } else {
          return ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: _buildCarsList(snapshot),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
```

And then the build function, I am not sure how to actually use the map based on the code that is working in Shri Hari's answer below to build tiles.

This is how you do the same thing for Firebase array fields that do NOT sit under a map, and works fine.   But adding the map layer means this no longer works:

```
_buildCarsList(AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
  return snapshot.data.data.values
    .map((doc) => doc[0] == "Toyota" ? Container(
      child: Text(
        doc[1],
      ),
    ),
```

---

### Edit1:

Shri Hari asked:  Can you please share the value of data after Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data;

Here is the output:

```
{CarsMap: {sh899873jsa: [Toyota, Supra, 1996, $4990], hasd823j399: [Toyota, Corolla, 2014, ], nelaoiwi283: [Ford, Territory, 2018, $35000]}}
```

---

### Original Question:

I am trying to make a repository of arrays, in the form of classes, in Firebase that users can create and then later edit and delete.

The only way I can think to do this is to have a unique identifier as the name of each array (class) so that each array can be uniquely identified.  The problem is that in Firebase, if the array identifier is at the top level, you can't talk to it at all, it is essentially invisible.

To resolve this, I believe the user-generated arrays need to sit under a map instead, so the database would look like so after users have created a few entries:

```
ObjectsList  >  CarsMap (Map)
 (document)      - sh899873jsa (Array)
                     0  "Toyota"
                     1  "Supra"
                     2  "1996"
                     3  "$4990"

                   - hasd823j399 (Array)
                     0  "Toyota"
                     1  "Corolla"
                     2  "2014"
                     3  "$11990"

                   - nelaoiwi283 (Array)
                     0  "Ford"
                     1  "Territory"
                     2  "2018"
                     3  "$35000"
```

But I don't know how to actually use this structure in Flutter, as I have never seen this before and I can't find anything at all online.   What I need to be able to do is build ListTiles from this data, and be able to select the specific arrays for editing/deletion ontap.

I have been dabbling with this code:

```
 final DocumentReference documents = await Firestore.instance.collection('ObjectsList');
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await documents.get();
  Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data;
  var loadCarItems = [];

  data.forEach((k,v) => {
    values = List<String>.from(v as List<String>),
    print(values),
    if (values[0] == "Toyota") {
      loadCarItems.add(values[0]),
    },
  });

  setState(() {
    CarItemsArray = loadCarItems;
  });
```

But I am getting an error on this line:

```
data.forEach((k,v) => {
  values = List<String>.from(v as List<String>),
```

The error being:

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast
```

Does anyone know the syntax to speak to a map of arrays like this?

Comment: Can you please share the value of `data` after `Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data;`?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.  I have answered your question in my original post above.

Answer (score 0):

I think we missed starting iterate in 'CarsMap', we did it in whole map.

```
data['CarsMap'].forEach((k,v) => {
    values = v,   // Since it is dynamic, it takes care of casting.
    print(values),
    if (values[0] == "Toyota") {
      loadCarItems.add(values[0]),
    },
});
```

or

```
data['CarsMap'].forEach((k,v) => {
     values = v.cast<String>(),   // Casting it to String
     print(values),
     if (values[0] == "Toyota") {
        loadCarItems.add(values[0]),
     },
});
```

Since it is not an array, `map()` won't do our need, instead apply the same above procedure.

```
_buildCarsList(snapshot) {
    List<Widget> listItems = [];
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();

    data['CarsMap'].forEach((k, v) {
      List<String> values = v.cast<String>();
      if (values[0] == "Toyota") {
        listItems.add(
          Container(
            child: Text(
              values[1],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
    
    return listItems;
  }
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.   I feel like I am so close to finally getting this working.   There is another error now:    Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast

Comment: Shall we try `values = v` itself? Since it is dynamic, it takes care of casting? Updated the answer

Comment: This no longer errors at all, which is fantastic.   What I get now is when I print loadCarItems I only get the values [Toyota, Toyota].   It is not populating the rest of the data.

Comment: Oh, it's simply because of the [0] haha.   The correct line is:  loadCarItems.add(values),

Comment: This no longer errors, which is great, but it doesn't solve my issue as I thought it might.  I have updated the question above, I am sure because this code resolves I am close now but just don't know the build syntax.

Comment: I too think you are close. Updated the answer. Please check it now

Comment: Thank you very much for your update!   I am getting an error now on this line:  Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data;   The error is "type 'DocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>"

Comment: Try addding `.document('ObjectsList').get()` on your stream builder.

Comment: Thanks, Shri Hari.   My current code for my streambuilder is listed in the question above.   When I use .get() instead of .snapshots() as you suggest, I get the error "The argument type Future<DocumentSnapshot> can't be assigned to the parameter type Stream<DocumentSnapshot>"

Comment: Then I think we have to go for `FutureBuilder` with our `.get()`.  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Ok, so now I replaced Streambuilder( with FutureBuilder(, and stream: with future: and now it correctly resolves .get().    The error now is here:  Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data;  and the error is "type DocumentSnapshot is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: I think we missed here : `snapshot.data.data();`  Updated the answer.

Comment: Reference: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read

Comment: Oh man, every time it seems we get closer, there is another hurdle.   With the new code I get:  Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'call'.  This is on the line with the updated snapshot.data.data();